# Update django model from background task

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update a django model from a task using `django-background-tasks`. Here's what I've got:

```
@background(schedule=0)
def difficult_work():
    for i in range(0,100):
        time.sleep(1)
        with transaction.atomic():
            workProgress = WorkProgress.objects.filter(id="fixed_work_id_for_testing").select_for_update().get()

            print("updating work progress to " + str(i))
            workProgress.progress = i
            workProgress.currentJobInfo = "test work"

            # if we've finished then make sure to set the status
            if i == 100:
                workProgress.status = "success"

            transfer.save(force_update=True)
```

Additionally, I have an API view to get the progress of a work task.

```
class WorkDetail(APIView):
def get(self, request, workId, format=None):
    with transaction.atomic():
        work = WorkProgress.objects.filter(id=workId).select_for_update().get()
        data = WorkProgressSerializer(transfer).data

        return Response(data)
```

The problem is, I'm not seeing any updates to the database while executing a task. I've got `python manage.py dbshell` running, monitoring the database tables and they aren't updating as the task progresses. I'm making sure to run `python manage.py process_tasks`, and it's outputting the correct `print` statements, indicating progress, but the database doesn't update until the task exits.

I found someone who ran into a similar problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/2QXcsT-c0zE), but they were only experiencing it in tests where they did not `get()` an updated model. However I'm not even seeing the database update in `dbshell`.

How do I make sure the table is updated while the task is running?

Note: according to [this](http://oddbird.net/2017/04/17/async-notifications/) site, they had some sort of success using `celery`. Can anyone confirm this? I will try it out and comment on viability.

Comment: I suggest you to use django channels from official developer to implement background task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your project **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
....
]

...
# Add to Option
BACKGROUND_TASK_RUN_ASYNC=True
```

Answer (score 1):

`django-background-tasks` seems to execute background tasks in atomic transactions (see [issue here](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/issues/113)), which means changes are only committed to the database after the tasks have completed.

They recently [removed the `@atomic` decorators](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/commit/bd569f45c57413d6d45cff28065fb88c5392212b), but didn't change the version number (it is currently still at 1.1.13).

Comment: This library has not received updates since 2019 (as of september 2021). But upgrading from 1.1.13 to 1.2.5 solved the issue for me, so that no longer the whole task is inside a single transaction.